# How is it possible to pull out derivatives of a wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differentiation

In an early derivation, the following equation was stated:

$$\frac\partial{\partial t}\lvert\psi\rvert^2 = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\biggl(\psi^*\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2\psi^*}{\partial x^2}\psi\biggr) = \frac\partial{\partial x}\biggl[\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\biggl(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial x}\psi\biggr)\biggr].$$

It appears as if the $\frac\partial{\partial x}$ was "taken out" from the expression. Is that valid? If so, why can't it be done a second time, i.e.
$$\frac\partial{\partial x}\biggl[\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\biggl(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial x}\psi\biggr)\biggr] = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\biggl[\frac{i\hbar}{2m}(\psi^*\psi - \psi^*\psi)\biggr] = 0.$$

If this is also valid, wouldn't the original be $\frac\partial{\partial t}\lvert\psi\rvert^2 = 0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's using the following:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(f \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - g \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) &=& \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - g\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \\
&=& f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} - g\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Oh god, so it's just an application of the product rule? I feel so stupid now as I would never have done what I asked in a maths question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Complimentarity don't be embarrassed, this kind of stuff is confusing. Actually, the notation physicists use for calculus (and in general for anything involving functions) is *really* bad when you get into anything moderately complex. The fundamental problem is that we conflate variables and functions. Anyway, as you go on in Griffiths I would recommend to take the perspective that the notation there is a *suggestion* and you should feel free to invent and use your own if it helps.

Comment: The magic of adding 0 ;)

Comment: @DanielSank eh... I don't know if I agree with that. Sure, operator notation has its problems, but I don't think those problems are responsible for _this_ question, and I don't think they are so severe at the level of Griffiths that it's useful to recommend scrapping the notation given and inventing your own. (Then again the idea that one should not be bound to a particular system of notation _is_ useful.)

Comment: @DavidZ I didn't really mean that this was the problem here. I was just hoping to give a hapless student who's using a confusing book some survival advice.

Comment: @DanielSank ah, I see. (Maybe off topic for the comment section, but whatever, I can always clean these up later.) In that case let me represent the counterpoint that I found Griffiths to be quite clear.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice! I tend to not notice pretty fundamental stuff when I'm following steps in an unfamiliar topic as I start assuming that any sort of mathematical technique would be new to me.